# Use iOS Keychain to store key & secret of API call

Tags: ios, ios6, keychain, read-write

I am storing the key & secret required for API call in iOS keychain using [Apple code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html)

My key & secret keeps on changing after every call to API. So once they are changed I save them in Keychain again. So I am accessging the iOS keychain frequently.
My questions are

1. Is it ok to store key & secret in iOS keychain ?
2. Does Apple allow this as I am accessing the keychain everytime I need to call API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. That's what it's there for.

You access your keychain every time you want to get in your car, right?

Comment: Thanks for info. I just want to confirm this.